# Spring Boot JPA error: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `7`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Trying to learn how to use Spring Boot (3.0.2).

I've created Spring Boot project with Intellij Idea.
The enitites and the repository I've created with JPA Buddy.
Controller is annotated @RestController

Intellij Idea doesn't report any problems and the App starting correctly, but then I invoke in browser localhost:9023/customers
I get the error:

```
2023-02-02T18:40:44.792+02:00 ERROR 27700 --- [nio-9023-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `7`] with root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
```

with long stackstrace following.

Googling the message "Unable to extract JDBC value for position" doesn't point to the explanation what this error mean.

Comment: Please add the full stack and the code where the stack is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Where was in one table two XML fields (MS SQL Server). JPA Buddy assigns their type as Map. For quick solution I've changed them to String.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was using @Builder without any constructor. Basically I was mapping JSON column from postgres to a pojo.

Solved by adding args annotation to the mapper class

```
...
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
...

@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor // was missing
@NoArgsConstructor // was missing
public class NotificationDetail {
    private String actionEntity;
    private String actionEntityId;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing enum Annotation on my field so that JPA knows how to insert this field

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```